# What is the owner of all_tab_statistics in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, statistics

What is the owner/schema of all_tab_statistics in Oracle 11g. Also how the query will execute if we didnt mention any schemas before table name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search the details of any object which is accessible to your schema then you can get the desired information from `ALL_OBJECTS` as follows:

> ```
> SQL> SELECT
>   2      OWNER,
>   3      OBJECT_NAME,
>   4      OBJECT_TYPE
>   5  FROM ALL_OBJECTS
>   6  WHERE OBJECT_NAME = 'ALL_TAB_STATISTICS';
>
> OWNER  OBJECT_NAME          OBJECT_TYP
> ------ -------------------- ----------
> SYS    ALL_TAB_STATISTICS   VIEW
> PUBLIC ALL_TAB_STATISTICS   SYNONYM
>
> SQL>
> ```

Here, As you can see that the `ALL_TAB_STATISTICS` is a view and is owned by `sys`.
And you are hitting the view using the `synonym` which is `PUBLIC`.

Hope this is very much clear.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

The query would execute depending if there are any public synonyms first. In other words if there are public synonyms for the object the you are querying oracle will try to select from that table. If there are no public syms than it would default to the schema where  you are running the query. The owner of all_tab_statistics view is `sys`. Hopefully that answers your question.